# How add custom node in a View (Nested View)?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, hooks

Currently I have simple view that is used on the main page. In includes nodes of custom type. That's great. But now I need to do something different.

Consider I have following structure:

-----View-----
-------Node 1--------
-------Node 2--------
-------Node 3--------
-------Node 4--------
-----End View-----

But I want to have the structure like that:

-----View-----
-------Node 1--------
-------Node 2--------
-------Node 3--------
---------View Nested in the node ---------
------------Nested Node 1-------------
------------Nested Node 2-------------
---------End Nested View ---------
-------Node 4--------
-----End View-----

So I need nest another view in a top level node.

How can I implement this?

Is there any way to do this using core functionality?
Otherwise I need to change the content of a node before data is passed to a template, but I don't which hook to use?

Please suggest how to deal with this task.

Comment: The structure is possible in core with a reference field for the nested nodes. If you want a view in a node to have more control on how the nested nodes should be displayed you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/eva.

Comment: @4k4 thank you so much could you please suggest what hooks can be used to modify node content, the plugin you've suggested it great, but I don't need to include it only for this task, I think it would be better for performacnce just to use a hook.

Comment: I only suggested EVA, because this would result exactly in the structure you want, including the second View for the nested nodes. As said, you don't need this or a hook, because displaying nested nodes is core functionality.

Comment: @4k4 Thank you so much could you post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to show the Nested Nodes (that should be a kind of Node Reference)

> There are a lot of cases in views where you want to embed a list
>   inside each row. One example could be, you have a list of groups, and
>   for each groups you want to list the first and last name of all of
>   their members.

For modify the content of a node you can use the [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x) maybe you will need to [Check content type of node in preprocess hook](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/206477/28275).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this module has not been update for a long time, so I think it is really better to use EVA

Comment: @ketazafor You can use EVA too, or a better way is implement your own pseudo-field and create a custom view_mode. https://www.webomelette.com/creating-pseudo-fields-drupal-8 to show the pseudo-field

Comment: Yeah, it was my initial idea to create field for example and type there my view name, and than handle it in the code, is it possible to do like that ?

Comment: @ketazafor, you can create a new view mode for your content type and a new pseudo-field with the list of nodes and show only this pseudo-field en the view mode, and in the view you can show the view_mode, or you can create a new custom field for the view https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-field-drupal-8